# Закрыт порт SSH на VirtualBox. Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, openssh

Поставил на виртуалку Ubuntu Server, установил openssh-server и изменил порт с 22 на 51200. Пробросил порты на роутере.

Внутренний IP моего ПК: 192.168.0.94
IP виртуалки: 192.168.0.88

По внутреннему все нормально заходит, а вот по внешнему не хочет. Проверил открытие портов через сервис hidemyname - порт открыт. Выключил ssh - порт закрыт. Значит доступ получает, но почему тогда не подключается?

Прикол в том, что если в роутере включить DMZ, то нормально подключается по внешнему, а без DMZ не хочет.

---

Попробовал подключиться через телефон по 3G - подключилось. Переключился на WiFi - не хочет подключаться к серверу.

Comment: Перенос портов в роутере настраивали?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы, находясь в локалке, цепляетесь к внешнему интерфейсу, оно пробрасывает на адрес в локалке с src ip из локалки же. Ядро видит что клиент из локалки и отвечает напрямую, а клиент ждёт ответа с другой машины и приезжающие пакеты отбрасывает как ошибочные.

Ва не только DNAT нужен, но еще и SNAT, чтобы сервер подменял ip клиента на свой.

Comment: Можно поподробней?